# Material-UI Slider Component: How to show values/marks in a different order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

By default the Material-UI slider shows marks/values in ascending order from min to max

For example, a slider with following config:

```
const marks = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: '1'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: '2'
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    label: '3'
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    label: '4'
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    label: '5'
  }
]

<Slider defaultValue={1} step={1} valueLabelDisplay="auto" onChange={handleChange} className={classes.slider} min={1} max={5} marks={marks} />
```

will render the slider like this: 1->2->3->4->5

I want to change the order in which the values/marks are displayed, something like this: 2->1->5->4->3 (Or any order in general, but other than the default 1 to 5)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ordering is done by the value field so you can relabel values like this:

```
const marks = [
  {
    value: 2,
    label: '1'
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: '2'
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    label: '3'
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    label: '4'
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    label: '5'
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

With array manipulation you can do that like this maybe:

```html
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr1 = arr.splice(2).reverse(); // arr1 = [2,1] arr = [3,4,5]
const arr2 = arr.reverse(); //[5,4,3]
const result = arr1.concat(arr2); // [2,1,5,4,3];
```

Comment: This question is not about simply rearranging values inside the original array. I have to format the Material-UI slider to display values in a different order

Comment: Then you can use the props `onChange` to reorder your array when the slider's value change, but if you want to change the Slider order, you have to change your array order